# Resharper does not recognize localized resources

Tags: localization, resharper

I am struggeling to get Resharper (7.1.3) to recognize localized resource files as described here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Resources__Editing_Resource_Value.html

I have a couple of resource files (Resource.resx, Resource.de-DE.resx, ...) with localized strings. The localization as such works fine as I can change the UI-culture as expected.

When I try to edit the resource value as described behind the above link, the R#'s edit window pops up but the "<<" and ">>" buttons are disabled and I can only edit the default culture.

Could sombody kindly tell me what I need to do, to tell R# what languages I want to use?

Thanks,Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a while I realized, that I added the localized resource file in the wrong way. I simply added the resource files via the project context menu and for some reason the corresponding designer files (e.g. Resources.de-DE.Designer.vb) were not created and that was the root of the problem.

To fix it I did the following:

1. Remove all resx-files, that didn't have a corresponding designer file
2. Copy the main Resources.resx file and rename it to match the wanted culture name.

That did it.